# Toggle visibility of a div by element with close current div shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following function to close all Div's of a class name. I am using OnClick event on a picture to run this function:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ElementInfo'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
       myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
    else
       e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

In the HTML I am using:

```
<a href="#"onclick="toggle_visibility('UserAccess');" ><img src="Images/files.png" width="542" height="117" /></a>
<a href="#"onclick="toggle_visibility('WhoSupports');"><img src="Images/Whotocall.png" width="542" height="118" />


<div class="ElementInfo" ID="UserAccess"><p>Info goes here</p></div>
<div class="ElementInfo" id="WhoSupports"><p>who to call info goes here</p></div>
```

This is working fine.

It does stop me from being able to hide the currently displayed div, I would like to be able to:

Click on the image to show the div.
Click on the image again to hide the div
Click on a different image to hide any divs (by class) and show a different div.

can this be done? I haven't been able to work it out.

Comment: provide some html code, too.

Comment: So each image has a div associated with it, and on click you would like to show that div?

Comment: Added the html Nelek.

Comment: Can I do a solution for you with jQuery?

Comment: Most of the divs have the same class, all have various ID's.

When a image is clicked, I want all the divs in the same class to be closed and the new div to open; unless, 

if the user clicks the same image a second time, I want it to just close the currently open div.

Currently, all divs load as hidden, a user clicks an image, and a div opens. they can click a different image, new div loads, but I cant return to no div's shown.

Comment: Unfortunately not Ted, I'm stuck in a stupidly restricted content management system.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (or I totally wrong :( ) :

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ElementInfo'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      if(myClasses[i]!=document.getElementById(id)) {
       myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
    else
       e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

If You click 1st image, 1st div opened. Then, if You click 2nd image, 1st div hide 2nd div opened. If You click on 2nd div, again, all divs, including 2nd div, hide. (?)

Comment: PERFECT! I see how that has worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution with jQuery. I have, as you should, separated the onClick events from the HTML code to the JavaScript code by using the click event bellow to call the function 'toggle_visibility'.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    toggle_visibility($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Here's the fiddle, with commented code so you can understand it:
http://jsfiddle.net/filipetedim/1s25u78L/1/